# Grouping words based on meaning and class

Tags: nltk, text-mining, synonym

I am looking for a package that groups words like "mom" and "women" and "female" in one group. In general something that groups words based on their class. In the above example the class would be Person:Female. I am working with NLTK similarity metrics but they dont seem to be doing well for my purposes. Is there anything else I can look at ?

Comment: Search for NLTK and synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are aware of the Wordnet project which may be what you are looking for. A lot of research has gone into this and in fact there is a global project to map this database to other languages. The lexical analysis is sound but as far as I know the data is stored in a bit of a messy format. The primary web site is here [Princeton Wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/). Also - if you search you will find a MSSQL version of the database and there is
client program to help you evaluate if the database is suitable for your purpose - this is called "Wordnet Browser". Link [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Other-Office-Tools/WordNet-Browser.shtml). I entered Mom and was able to get Female , Person and Mother out of the hypernym related terms. There is a lot of lexical terms to learn here and I haven't gotten to the bottom of it myself.
 But I hope this is of help to you.

Comment: Thanks alot. I am using wordnet via python. But when I try to get hypernym of mom using python's nltk package I get:

['entity', 'physical_entity', 'object', 'whole', 'living_thing', 'organism', 'person', 'relative', 'ancestor', 'progenitor', 'genitor', 'parent', 'mother', 'ma']
['entity', 'physical_entity', 'causal_agent', 'person', 'relative', 'ancestor', 'progenitor', 'genitor', 'parent', 'mother', 'ma']

Comment: Yaah its fine but I dont see Female in there. @Noggin I dont see Female in there.

Comment: Female comes out as a sense of mom in wordnet. The sense is "female parent". I'm not familiar with the package you are using. It might be worth including sense lookups if possible.